# What does movl (%eax, %edx, 4), %ecx instruction do?

Tags: assembly, x86, mov

I have a very brief understanding of assembly and am confused as to what this code below does?

```
movl (%eax, %edx, 4), %ecx
```

My understanding is that `%edx` is being multiplied by 4 and then being added with the value of of `%eax` and then being stored in `%ecx` This is the table given with the values

[Register Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bL5qE.png)

The answer given is 0x11 however I don't get that answer.

Comment: In AT&T syntax the usage of `(..)` parentheses hints that memory content is being fetched/written. Unfortunately that rule is not followed everywhere, certain instructions enforce memory usage without `()` syntax (when the instruction doesn't make sense for non-memory usage). In Intel syntax the memory access is marked by `[]`, used much more rigorously with all (?) instructions (`lea` is kind of exception using the `mov` syntax, but not accessing memory). So with AT&T syntax you have to read the instruction fully to tell whether memory is accessed or not, but with `()` it's safe bet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDX is multiplied by four, added to EAX, a 4 byte value is read from memory at that address, and placed into ECX.

MOV, in general, doesn't perform arithmetic, unless it's address calculation.

---

In your particular case: `edx = 3`, `eax = 0x100`, `temporary_address_in_CPU_during_mov = eax + edx * 4 = 0x100 + 3*4 = 0x10C`. Value in memory at address `0x10C` is `0x11`.

This address arithmetic can be used itself through `lea` instruction, when the CPU will do the address math, but instead of loading value from memory it will just store the calculated address, so:

```
leal (%eax, %edx, 4), %ecx
```

will load `ecx` with value `0x10C` (without accessing memory). This is sometimes "tricked" for doing simple arithmetic, like `eax = 5*eax` : `lea (eax,eax,4),eax` (may be faster than `imul` and doesn't change flag register, sometimes handy).